# What is the standard : long or short scales

Tags: number-systems

I know about [long and short scales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales) of numbering systems, but I want to know, what is the standard naming of large numbers?!! is that back on the long scale or the short scale?!! so if someone in the world say **1 billion**, so I've to take it as `10^9` or `10^12`?

I came across [this Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_large_numbers) which clarifies some countries/regions that use short scale and some others that use long scale, but this is already not a clear answer to my question.

Comment: If it's written in English, assume short scale. (The UK used to use the long scale, but not any more.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've answered your own question:

> some countries/regions that use short scale and some others that use long scale

There is no standard. Unfortunately. Just as how English words and idioms are different depending on where you say it and to whom.